# Sketch of region bounded by a circle, line and axis and set up the single double integral in rectangular coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant of the plane bounded by the $x^2 + y^2 = 9$, the $x$-axis, and the line $y=x$. Sketch the region $R$.

I have tried to sketch the region $R$, but I don't know whether I am doing it the right way..

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Sketch the circle with centre at $(0,0)$ and radius equal to $3$. Then Sketch the line $y=x$, which divides the 1st quadrant. You have also the x-axis. Finally you'll have a "pizza slice" (circular sector) of angle $\pi/4$ and radius $3$.

Comment: Thank you..How can you set up a single double integral in rectangular coordinates that can be used to find the area of the region R?

Comment: Pizza slices like that are typically called [circular sectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector).

Comment: @Chou5 If you know the area of the full circular disk, it is easier to just divide that number by ... (what integer?).

Comment: The area of a sector with central angle $\theta$ in a disk with radius $r$ is $$A = \frac{\theta}{2\pi} \pi r^2 = \frac{\theta}{2} r^2$$ where $\theta$ is measured in radians.

Comment: @Chou5, also take a look here, I think you'll find it useful: http://math.harvard.edu/~ytzeng/worksheet/1026_sol.pdf